# How to use more than one middleware in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I am trying to use 2 middlewares for my route, auth.js and authAdmin.js which are in different folder.

var middleware = [auth, authAdmin]
router.get("/all_infor", middleware, userCtrl.getUsersAllInfor)

Official page of Expressjs defined the same way I did above but I am getting error:

```
   F:\Mern projects\full_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
   throw new Error(msg);
     ^

 Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
 at Route.<computed> [as get] (F:\Mern 
 projects\full_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
 at Function.proto.<computed> [as get] (F:\Mern 
 projects\full_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Mern projects\full_auth\routes\userRouter.js:25:8)
```

can any one suggest how do I fix this? Thank You in advance.

Comment: This sounds like `auth` or `authAdmin` are not proper middleware functions.  Can you show the rest of the code that shows where those come from, how they are imported nd exported?

Comment: Since you solved your own problem without providing enough code for us to write an answer, you can either write your own answer (and then accept it) or you can delete your question.  It shouldn't be left in the state it's in where there is insufficient information for anyone to answer.